# Wrong syntax in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write one of my first SQL queries, but it seems like the syntax is wrong. I've gone over it for the past two hours trying to change things back and forth, but it still seems to be wrong somewhere on line 3. Could someone help me?

```
SELECT prodotti.ID_Prodotto, prodotti.ID_Ditta, 
      prodotti.Nome, prodotti.Descrizione, prodotti.ID_Tipologia, 
      prodotti.Immagine, cp.Nome, valori.Valore 
FROM prodotti, campi tipologia as cp, valori 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
    and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia 
    and (valori.ID_prodotto = prodotti.ID_prodotto 
    and valori.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

This is the error message I get:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as cp, valori WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_ti' at line 3
```

Comment: `campi tipologia as cp,` - there's a space too many. Maybe the table is named `campi_tipologia`?

Comment: First of all format your SQL so that each major clause is easily separated visually and discernible from the others (as I did above)

Comment: Theres a space in one of the tables

Comment: and the table referred to as `campi tipologia' should probably have an underscore, (or something) in it instead of a space... If it really is two words, then you need to surround it with brackets or quotes.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, as Drew and @CharlesBretana pointed out I had to enclose the table name with a space in it to make it work.

Comment: If you are learning SQL, you should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *never* use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: and never use table names with spaces in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to back-tick the table name with a space in it, if that is a table name with a space in it.

Otherwise, yet another table, and you need a comma ?

```
SELECT prodotti.ID_Prodotto, prodotti.ID_Ditta, prodotti.Nome, prodotti.Descrizione,
prodotti.ID_Tipologia, prodotti.Immagine, cp.Nome, valori.Valore 
FROM prodotti, `campi tipologia` as cp, valori 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia 
and (valori.ID_prodotto= prodotti.ID_prodotto and valori.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

Yes, see below, I guess it is possible to have a table name with a space. Never tried it before to be honest

```
create table `a b`
(
    id int
);
```

Comment: It was only one table, didn't know you were forced to backtick the name in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL have a typpo at:

```
campi tipologia AS cp,
```

remove spaces between 2 tables;

Comment: It was only one table, needed to back-tick the name as per @Drew 's answer

Answer (score 1):

the table referred to as `campi tipologia' should probably have an underscore, (or something) in it instead of a space... If it really is two words, then you need to surround it with brackets or quotes.

either

```
SELECT prodotti.ID_Prodotto, prodotti.ID_Ditta, 
    prodotti.Nome, prodotti.Descrizione, prodotti.ID_Tipologia, 
    prodotti.Immagine, cp.Nome, valori.Valore 
FROM prodotti, [campi tipologia] as cp, valori 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
  and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia 
  and (valori.ID_prodotto = prodotti.ID_prodotto 
  and valori.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

or

```
SELECT prodotti.ID_Prodotto, prodotti.ID_Ditta, 
    prodotti.Nome, prodotti.Descrizione, prodotti.ID_Tipologia, 
    prodotti.Immagine, cp.Nome, valori.Valore 
FROM prodotti, "campi tipologia" as cp, valori 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
  and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia 
  and (valori.ID_prodotto = prodotti.ID_prodotto 
  and valori.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

or

```
SELECT prodotti.ID_Prodotto, prodotti.ID_Ditta, 
    prodotti.Nome, prodotti.Descrizione, prodotti.ID_Tipologia, 
    prodotti.Immagine, cp.Nome, valori.Valore 
FROM prodotti, campi_tipologia as cp, valori 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
  and cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia 
  and (valori.ID_prodotto = prodotti.ID_prodotto 
  and valori.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

Even better, use aliases for all your table names:

```
SELECT p.ID_Prodotto, p.ID_Ditta, 
    p.Nome, p.Descrizione, p.ID_Tipologia, 
    p.Immagine, cp.Nome, v.Valore 
FROM prodotti p, [campi tipologia] as cp, valori v 
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
  and cp.ID_tipologia = p.ID_tipologia 
  and v.ID_prodotto = p.ID_prodotto 
  and v.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo);
```

and the new (since 1992) join syntax...

```
SELECT p.ID_Prodotto, p.ID_Ditta, 
    p.Nome, p.Descrizione, p.ID_Tipologia, 
    p.Immagine, cp.Nome, v.Valore 
FROM prodotti p
   Join [campi tipologia] cp 
       on cp.ID_tipologia = p.ID_tipologia 
   Join valori v 
       on v.ID_prodotto = p.ID_prodotto 
          and v.ID_Campo_Tipologia = cp.ID_campo
WHERE prodotti.ID_Ditta = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of what you are trying to achive? And do you have a bit more info about the structure of the databases? For me it looks a bit too much, like you are trying to achieve something that maybe is easier. Found one bit of the code that might be wrong, is it that you have mistaken what comes first of declaration?

```
cp.ID_tipologia = prodotti.ID_tipologia
```